# C++ объекты одного класса в поле другого класса

Tags: c++, ооп

В одном классе у меня храниться вектор с объектами другого класса. после их создания и добавления их в вектор и выхода за скобку они все дохнут. Пробовал вектор с указателями, пробовал в классе, объекты которого должны храниться делать конструктор копирования. Но не могу потом вызвать метод у объекта который должен храниться в векторе, там мусор в нем, а не нужные данные. Как создавать объекты и добавлять их в вектор, чтобы они не сдыхали и можно было вызывать их методы, обращаясь к элементу вектора. Я совсем запутался что-то, неделю на С++. До этого на джава и шарпах таких проблем не было.

```
#pragma once
#include "../Game Objects/World/TileObject.h"
#include "../Game Objects/World/Block_Solid.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "Cell.h"
#include "../Engine/ResourceManager.h"
//#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>
#include <memory>


class Level
{
private:
    bool generatedDone; // сгенерирован ли уровень
    unsigned int _cellsInWidth, _cellsInHeight;
    std::string _levelName; 
    std::vector<Cell> _level;       
public:
    Level(const int cellsInWidth, const int cellsInHeight, const std::string &levelName);           
    void generateLevel();
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow & window);
    ~Level();
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


#include "Level.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

Level::Level(const int cellsInWidth, const int cellsInHeight, const std::string &levelName):
    _cellsInWidth(cellsInWidth), _cellsInHeight(cellsInHeight), _levelName(levelName)
{}

void Level::generateLevel() {
    _level.push_back(Cell(10, 10, "Dungeon_Floor_1"));
    generatedDone = true;
}



void Level::draw(sf::RenderWindow & window) {

    for (auto it = _level.begin(); it != _level.end(); it++) {

        (it)->draw(window);//здесь элемент вектора, который с мусором, то есть дохлый
    }
}
Level::~Level() {}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma once
#include "World\TileObject.h"
#include <memory>
#include "World\Dungeon_Floor_1.h"
class Cell
    //участок на уровне (базовый тайл (пол, стена итп), на котором лежат предметы и имеет координаты итп)
{private:
    unsigned int x_coord, y_coord;
    TileObject* _baseTile; //основной тайл клетки - пол, стена, вода итп

public:
    Cell(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, const std::string& objectname);
    ~Cell();
    Cell(const Cell &obj);
    void draw(sf::RenderTarget & window);
};
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include "Cell.h"

Cell::Cell(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, const std::string& objectname): x_coord(x), y_coord(y)
{
    if (objectname == "Dungeon_Floor_1") {

        _baseTile = new Dungeon_Floor_1();
    }

}


Cell::~Cell()
{
    delete _baseTile;
}

Cell::Cell(const Cell & obj)
{   x_coord = obj.x_coord;
    y_coord = obj.y_coord;
    _baseTile = obj._baseTile;}
```

UPD
Сделал. Я не хотел связываться с оператором new, но так понял без него не получиться ничего.

```
void Level::generateLevel() {   
    Cell* c = new Cell(10, 10, "Dungeon_Floor_1");
    _level.push_back(c);
    generatedDone = true;
}
Level::~Level() {
    for (auto it = _level.begin(); it != _level.end(); it++) {

        delete *it;
    }

}
```

Все рисуется одна тестовая ячейка уровня. как и хотел. Не будет ли тут утечки?

Comment: Хоть какой-то код покажите, чтоб понять, КАК вы это делали...

Comment: прислал два .cpp, два .h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал. Я не хотел связываться с оператором new, но так понял без него не получиться ничего.

```
void Level::generateLevel() {   
    Cell* c = new Cell(10, 10, "Dungeon_Floor_1");
    _level.push_back(c);
    generatedDone = true;
}
Level::~Level() {
    for (auto it = _level.begin(); it != _level.end(); it++) {

        delete *it;
    }

}
```

Все рисуется одна тестовая ячейка уровня. как и хотел.
Не будет ли тут утечки?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, я сразу вижу одну проблему - смотрите, вы в деструкторе `Cell` освобождаете `_baseTile`:

```
Cell::~Cell()
{
    delete _baseTile;
}
```

Но в конструкторе копирования этот указатель просто копируется:

```
Cell::Cell(const Cell & obj)
{   x_coord = obj.x_coord;
    y_coord = obj.y_coord;
    _baseTile = obj._baseTile;
}
```

Так что при уничтожении одного объекта `Cell` в другом уже оказывается невалидный указатель - на удаленную память. При повторном уничтожении получится очень плохо - повторное освобождение.

```
_level.push_back(Cell(10, 10, "Dungeon_Floor_1"));
```

Вот тут - временный `Cell` уничтожается после выхода из `push_back` и делает невалидным `_baseTile`.

Дальше - у вас **всегда** передается `"Dungeon_Floor_1"`? Если нет - то и `_baseTile` в конструкторе инициализируется не всегда.

Это так, то, что видно сразу, навскидку. Не говорю, что это все неприятности, но этих уже хватает...

Comment: "Dungeon_Floor_1" это просто тест. См. новый вопрос от меня)